# The marker is not showing

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add markers to rotating globe object with Three.js - the globe is showing, but the markers is not displayed. I don't know why this happens, the console.log dont throw any errors to debug anything.

Can someone help me find the root to this issue and correct it?

The code inside the index.html file is down below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="threejs" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>

        <script>
var boards = []; 
var texture = []; 
var matTexture = [];



            var camera, scene, renderer, controls, container, materialBoard, boardGeo,materialSph, sphGeo, sphere,picGeo;


            init();
            animate();

            function init() {


                scene  = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 300000 );
                scene.add( camera );
                camera.position.set( 0, 1500, 5000);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias:true } );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee );

                container = document.getElementById( 'threejs' );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );


                var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

                texture[0] = loader.load( "test.png" );
                matTexture[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:0xffffff, map: texture[0], transparent:true, opacity:1, wireframe:false} );    
    
                // ball

                materialSph = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0099dd, transparent: true, opacity: 0.8, wireframe:false } );
                sphGeo  = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1200, 8, 8);
                sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphGeo, materialSph );
                scene.add( sphere );


                // board for some things    
                materialBoard   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xdddddd, transparent:true, opacity:0.4, wireframe: true });
                boardGeo  = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500,500);

                picGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 500 );
                const vertices = sphGeo.attributes.position.array;
                console.log(vertices);

    
    var board = new THREE.Mesh( boardGeo, materialBoard );              // board for pictures etc.     
        var pic = new THREE.Mesh( picGeo, matTexture[ 0 ] );        
        board.add( pic ) ;                                              //  add picture to the board
        
        boards.push( board );
        scene.add( boards[ 0 ] );                                   
        
        boards[ 0 ].position.set( 1 * vertices[ 10 ].x , 0.5 * vertices[ 2 ].y, 1.8 * vertices[ 10 ].z ); 
    



            }

    

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

for( var n = 0; n < boards.length; n ++ ) {
        
        //boards[ n ].lookAt( camera.position );
        boards[ n ].quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );
     }  
     
            renderer.render( scene, camera );   
    
    controls.update();

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `sphGeo.attributes.position.array` is the array of numbers, so the numbers don't have `x`, `y`, `z` properties.

Comment: Thank you how do i get the vertices x, y and x

Comment: `boards[0].position.fromBufferAttribute(sphGeo.attributes.position, _vertex_index_ );`, something like that.